# Binutils build fails on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite

Tags: macos, unix, gnu, binutils

After downloading the package of GNU Binutils 2.25

I followed the instructions on "Installing Binutils":

**./cnofigure**

**make**

errors happened after build:

```
../../binutils-gdb/binutils/nm.c:1733:28: error: 'sbrk' is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      char *lim = (char *) sbrk (0);

/usr/include/unistd.h:582:7: note: 'sbrk' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
void    *sbrk(int);

1 error generated.
make[4]: *** [nm.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-binutils] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I did some research on net and they said using this command

**./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-werror**

and I get

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-recursive   
make[8]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'. 
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all-target'.
```

(what does that mean "nothing to be done for all-am and all-target")

I don't know what to do anymore.
Is it a bug or it's me doing something wrong?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really would make life easier for yourself if you used `homebrew` as a package manager on OSX.

Goto the [homebrew website](http://brew.sh) and copy and paste the one-line install script into your Terminal.

Then you can install `binutils` simply by typing

```
brew install binutils
```

If, down the line, you want to find GNU sed, or ImageMagick, you can just do

```
brew search sed
```

or

```
brew search imagemagick
```

then

```
brew install sed
```

If you have any problems, just run

```
brew doctor
```

If you want to update all your packages, just run

```
brew update
brew upgrade --all
```

More cool ideas and suggestions [here](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/).

Comment: thanks for the post. Now i have successfully installed binutils, but how am I suppose to run the tools inside it? For example if I want to run objdump, have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: oh I figured it out myself, all the tools have a prefix of 'g' objdump becomes gobjdump, ar -> gar (although I have no idea why is there a 'g' added before). But I'm able to use all the tools now. Thanks for the post again.

Answer (score 1):

After build failure , you should clean previously generated object files

So,

```
make clean

./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-werror

make
```