# Compile ImageMagick from source with PNG support on OSX

Tags: macos, imagemagick

I need to compile it from sources. I followed step by step [instruction](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1146055) to build it with jpeg and png support but ImageMagick didn't include PNG to delegates list however jpeg has been included. What is wrong with PNG?

```
Options used to compile and link:
PREFIX          = /opt/im
EXEC-PREFIX     = /opt/im
VERSION         = 6.9.2
CC              = gcc
CFLAGS          =   -g -O2 -Wall -mtune=haswell -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
CPPFLAGS        =   -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/jpeg -I/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/magick -I/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/png -I/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/wand
PCFLAGS         = 
DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LDFLAGS         =  -L/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/jpeg/.libs -L/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/jpeg -L/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/magick -L/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/png/.libs -L/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/png -L/tmp/IM/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10/wand
LIBS            = 
CXX             = g++
CXXFLAGS        = -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
FEATURES        = DPC Cipher
DELEGATES       = mpeg jpeg
```

Comment: Why not make life easy for yourself and install using `homebrew`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32153599/2836621

Comment: the goal is compile IM from sources without homebrew or makports

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I would install ImageMagick from source on OSX.

**1. Install Xcode**

First, you are going to need the Apple compiler and development tools whatever you do. So, start the `AppStore` which looks like this:

[image]

and download `Xcode` for free - it looks like this:

[image]

**2. Install Command Line Tools**

Once you have `Xcode` installed, you need to install the command-line tools (i.e. clang, clang++, make) like this:

```
xcode-select --install
```

**3. Choose Your Method - `homebrew` or a `Life of Agony`™**

Now you need to choose how you are going to proceed. The simplest option, by miles and miles and miles, is to use `homebrew`. The other method is self-descriptive.

**3a. homebrew Method**

Go to the [homebrew website](http://brew.sh) and copy and paste the one-liner there into your Terminal - I won't show it here because it may change and I want you and future readers to use the current command. Once `homebrew` is installed, you just do this to choose your ImageMagick options:

```
brew options imagemagick

--with-fftw
    Compile with FFTW support
--with-fontconfig
    Build with fontconfig support
--with-ghostscript
    Build with ghostscript support
--with-hdri
    Compile with HDRI support
--with-jp2
    Compile with Jpeg2000 support
--with-liblqr
    Build with liblqr support
--with-librsvg
    Build with librsvg support
--with-libwmf
    Build with libwmf support
--with-little-cms
    Build with little-cms support
--with-little-cms2
    Build with little-cms2 support
--with-openexr
    Build with openexr support
--with-openmp
    Compile with OpenMP support
--with-pango
    Build with pango support
--with-perl
    enable build/install of PerlMagick
--with-quantum-depth-16
    Compile with a quantum depth of 16 bit
--with-quantum-depth-32
    Compile with a quantum depth of 32 bit
--with-quantum-depth-8
    Compile with a quantum depth of 8 bit
--with-webp
    Build with webp support
--with-x11
    Build with x11 support
--without-freetype
    Build without freetype support
--without-jpeg
    Build without jpeg support
--without-libpng
    Build without libpng support
--without-libtiff
    Build without libtiff support
--without-magick-plus-plus
    disable build/install of Magick++
--without-opencl
    Disable OpenCL
```

and then having selected your options, you install with

```
brew install imagemagick --with-perl --with-librsvg
```

or whatever you want. Then you are finished and you don't need to read the following torture!

Later on, upgrades are simple:

```
brew update && brew upgrade --all
```

Problem-solving is simple:

```
brew doctor
```

Uninstallation is simple:

```
brew rm imagemagick
```

**3b. Life of Agony™ Method**

Ok, I see you sadly decided on a `Life of Agony`™, so be it. I hope you know `tar`, `bash`, environment variables, `gzip`, `make`, `curl`. Now would be a good time to think again and use `homebrew` after all....

Sure you want to proceed? Ok, the general idea is to decide what features you need, install the features first, then install ImageMagick.

**4. Set up a build area and environment**

Set up two directories and 2 environment vars in your $HOME/.profile. These will be the `build` area where you build software and the `sw` area where you install your local software to:

```
export MSBUILD=$HOME/build
export MSSW=$HOME/sw
```

Now source your profile into your current session with

```
. $HOME/.profile
```

or just log out and log back in so that the variables above take effect.

Next create the two directories:

```
mkdir "$MSBUILD" "$MSSW"
```

**5. Consider Features you need**

Now consider what features you need:

**5.1 Feature = PNG Support**

If you need PNG support, you need `zlib` first. In your web-browser, go to the [zlib website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/zlib/) and find the name of the latest version. Then in Terminal:

```
cd $MSBUILD
curl -O -J -L http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/zlib/1.2.8/zlib-1.2.8.tar.xz/download
```

which gets you this `zlib-1.2.8.tar.xz` (or similar) which you can unpack and install with:

```
tar xvfJ zlib*.tar.xz          # Unzip and untar what you downloaded
cd zlib*[0-9]                  # Change directory to wherever it unpacked to
./configure --prefix="$MSSW"   # Configure with the necessary prefix
make
make install
```

Now you want `libpng` which you do with:

```
curl -O -J -L http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/latest/download?source=files
```

which gets you this (or similar):

```
libpng-1.6.17.tar.xz
```

which you install with this command:

```
tar xvfJ libpng*xz             # Unpack and untar whatever you downloaded
cd libpng*[0-9]                # Change directory to wherever it unpacked to
./configure --prefix="$MSSW"   # Configure with the necessary prefix
make 
make install
```

**5.2 Feature = TIFF Support**

If you need TIFF support, use this:

```
cd $MSBUILD
curl -O -J -L ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/libtiff/tiff-4.0.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz tiff*tar.gz             # Unzip and untar what you downloaded
cd tiff*[0-9]                    # Change directory to wherever it unpacked to
./configure --prefix="$MSSW"     # Configure with the necessary prefix
make
make install
```

**5.3 Feature = WEBP Support**

If you need WEBP support, use this:

```
cd $MSBUILD
curl -O -J -L http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-0.4.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz libwebp*tar.gz          # Unzip and untar what you downloaded
cd libwebp*[0-9]                 # Change directory to wherever it unpacked to
./configure --prefix="$MSSW"     # Configure with the necessary prefix
make
make install
```

**5.4 Feature = JPEG Support**

If you need JPEG support, use this:

```
cd $MSBUILD
curl -O -J -L http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz
tar xvfz jpeg*tar.gz                 # Unzip and untar what you downloaded
cd jpeg-9a                           # Change directory to wherever it unpacked to
./configure --prefix="$MSSW"         # Configure with the necessary prefix
make
make install
```

**5.5 Feature - X11 or X Windows**

As OSX no longer ships with an X11 server, you will need to install one yourself if you wish to use X11. Now, if you had taken my advice and used `homebrew`, you would be able to do:

```
brew cask install xquartz
```

and you would be finished. But you chose the `Life of Agony` ™ option, so you will have to figure out how to install XQuartz yourself.

**6. ImageMagick itself**

Once you have all the features you want installed, you can install ImageMagick. Get your copy [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download), then install like this:

```
cd $MSBUILD
gunzip ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar -xvf ImageMagick.tar
cd ImageMagick-6.9.1-2       # or wherever the tar-file extracted to
```

Now choose your options. How do you know the options available? You run:

```
./configure --help
```

and you will get a daunting array of options like this:

```
`configure' configures ImageMagick 6.9.2-10 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/ImageMagick]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

Program names:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
  --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
  --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names

X features:
  --x-includes=DIR    X include files are in DIR
  --x-libraries=DIR   X library files are in DIR

System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]
  --target=TARGET   configure for building compilers for TARGET [HOST]

Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-silent-rules   less verbose build output (undo: "make V=1")
  --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")
  --enable-reproducible-build
                          enable reproducible build
  --enable-dependency-tracking
                          do not reject slow dependency extractors
  --disable-dependency-tracking
                          speeds up one-time build
  --enable-ld-version-script
                          enable linker version script (default is enabled
                          when possible)
  --enable-bounds-checking
                          enable run-time bounds-checking
  --enable-osx-universal-binary
                          build universal binary on OS X [[default=no]]
  --disable-openmp        do not use OpenMP
  --enable-opencl         enable OpenCL support
  --disable-largefile     omit support for large files
  --enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-fast-install[=PKGS]
                          optimize for fast installation [default=yes]
  --disable-libtool-lock  avoid locking (might break parallel builds)
  --enable-delegate-build look for delegate libraries in build directory
  --disable-deprecated    exclude deprecated methods in MagickCore and
                          MagickWand APIs
  --disable-installed     Formally install ImageMagick under PREFIX
  --disable-cipher        disable enciphering and deciphering image pixels
  --enable-zero-configuration
                          enable self-contained, embeddable,
                          zero-configuration ImageMagick
  --enable-hdri           accurately represent the wide range of intensity
                          levels found in real scenes
  --disable-assert        disable assert() statements in build
  --enable-maintainer-mode
                          enable make rules and dependencies not useful (and
                          sometimes confusing) to the casual installer
  --enable-hugepages      enable 'huge pages' support
  --enable-ccmalloc       enable 'ccmalloc' memory debug support
  --enable-efence         enable 'efence' memory debug support
  --enable-prof           enable 'prof' profiling support
  --enable-gprof          enable 'gprof' profiling support
  --enable-gcov           enable 'gcov' profiling support
  --disable-assert        turn off assertions
  --disable-docs          disable building of documentation

Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-gnu-ld           assume the C compiler uses GNU ld [default=no]
  --with-dmalloc          use dmalloc, as in http://www.dmalloc.com
  --with-gcc-arch=<arch>  use architecture <arch> for gcc -march/-mtune,
                          instead of guessing
  --includearch-dir=DIR   ARCH specific include directory
  --sharearch-dir=DIR     ARCH specific config directory
  --with-pkgconfigdir=DIR Path to the pkgconfig directory [LIBDIR/pkgconfig]
  --without-threads       disable threads support
  --with-pic[=PKGS]       try to use only PIC/non-PIC objects [default=use
                          both]
  --with-aix-soname=aix|svr4|both
                          shared library versioning (aka "SONAME") variant to
                          provide on AIX, [default=aix].
  --with-sysroot[=DIR]    Search for dependent libraries within DIR (or the
                          compiler's sysroot if not specified).
  --with-modules          enable building dynamically loadable modules
  --with-method-prefix=PREFIX
                          prefix MagickCore API methods
  --with-quantum-depth=DEPTH
                          number of bits in a pixel quantum (default 16)
  --with-cache=THRESHOLD  set pixel cache threshhold in MB (default available
                          memory)
  --with-frozenpaths      freeze delegate paths
  --without-magick-plus-plus
                          disable build/install of Magick++
  --with-package-release-name=NAME
                          encode this name into the shared library
  --with-perl             enable build/install of PerlMagick
  --with-perl-options=OPTIONS
                          options to pass on command-line when generating
                          PerlMagick build file
  --with-jemalloc         enable jemalloc memory allocation library support
  --with-umem             enable umem memory allocation library support
  --with-libstdc=DIR      use libstdc++ in DIR (for GNU C++)
  --without-bzlib         disable BZLIB support
  --with-x                use the X Window System
  --without-zlib          disable ZLIB support
  --with-apple-font-dir=DIR
                          Apple font directory
  --with-autotrace        enable autotrace support
  --without-dps           disable Display Postscript support
  --with-dejavu-font-dir=DIR
                          DejaVu font directory
  --without-fftw          disable FFTW support
  --without-fpx           disable FlashPIX support
  --without-djvu          disable DjVu support
  --without-fontconfig    disable fontconfig support
  --without-freetype      disable Freetype support
  --with-gslib            enable Ghostscript library support
  --with-fontpath=DIR     prepend to default font search path
  --with-gs-font-dir=DIR  Ghostscript font directory
  --with-gvc              enable GVC support
  --without-jbig          disable JBIG support
  --without-jpeg          disable JPEG support
  --without-lcms          disable lcms (v1.1X) support
  --without-openjp2       disable OpenJP2 support
  --without-lqr           disable Liquid Rescale support
  --without-lzma          disable LZMA support
  --without-openexr       disable OpenEXR support
  --without-pango         disable PANGO support
  --without-png           disable PNG support
  --with-rsvg             enable RSVG support
  --without-tiff          disable TIFF support
  --without-webp          disable WEBP support
  --with-windows-font-dir=DIR
                          Windows font directory
  --with-wmf              enable WMF support
  --without-xml           disable XML support

Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  PKG_CONFIG  path to pkg-config utility
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH
              directories to add to pkg-config's search path
  PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
              path overriding pkg-config's built-in search path
  LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH
              User-defined run-time library search path.
  CXXCPP      C++ preprocessor
  XMKMF       Path to xmkmf, Makefile generator for X Window System
  ZLIB_CFLAGS C compiler flags for ZLIB, overriding pkg-config
  ZLIB_LIBS   linker flags for ZLIB, overriding pkg-config
  AUTOTRACE_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for AUTOTRACE, overriding pkg-config
  AUTOTRACE_LIBS
              linker flags for AUTOTRACE, overriding pkg-config
  fftw3_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for fftw3, overriding pkg-config
  fftw3_LIBS  linker flags for fftw3, overriding pkg-config
  ddjvuapi_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for ddjvuapi, overriding pkg-config
  ddjvuapi_LIBS
              linker flags for ddjvuapi, overriding pkg-config
  FONTCONFIG_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for FONTCONFIG, overriding pkg-config
  FONTCONFIG_LIBS
              linker flags for FONTCONFIG, overriding pkg-config
  FREETYPE_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for FREETYPE, overriding pkg-config
  FREETYPE_LIBS
              linker flags for FREETYPE, overriding pkg-config
  GVC_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for GVC, overriding pkg-config
  GVC_LIBS    linker flags for GVC, overriding pkg-config
  LCMS2_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for LCMS2, overriding pkg-config
  LCMS2_LIBS  linker flags for LCMS2, overriding pkg-config
  LIBOPENJP2_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for LIBOPENJP2, overriding pkg-config
  LIBOPENJP2_LIBS
              linker flags for LIBOPENJP2, overriding pkg-config
  LQR_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for LQR, overriding pkg-config
  LQR_LIBS    linker flags for LQR, overriding pkg-config
  LZMA_CFLAGS C compiler flags for LZMA, overriding pkg-config
  LZMA_LIBS   linker flags for LZMA, overriding pkg-config
  OPENEXR_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for OPENEXR, overriding pkg-config
  OPENEXR_LIBS
              linker flags for OPENEXR, overriding pkg-config
  PANGO_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for PANGO, overriding pkg-config
  PANGO_LIBS  linker flags for PANGO, overriding pkg-config
  PNG_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for PNG, overriding pkg-config
  PNG_LIBS    linker flags for PNG, overriding pkg-config
  RSVG_CFLAGS C compiler flags for RSVG, overriding pkg-config
  RSVG_LIBS   linker flags for RSVG, overriding pkg-config
  CAIRO_SVG_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for CAIRO_SVG, overriding pkg-config
  CAIRO_SVG_LIBS
              linker flags for CAIRO_SVG, overriding pkg-config
  XML_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for XML, overriding pkg-config
  XML_LIBS    linker flags for XML, overriding pkg-config

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.

Report bugs to <http://www.imagemagick.org>.
```

Once you have chosen your options, install with a command that looks like this:

```
./configure --prefix="$MSSW" --with-modules --disable-docs --without-x --enable-hdri=yes --with-quantum-depth=16
make
make install
```

Now add $MSSW/bin to your PATH in $HOME/.profile.

```
export PATH=$HOME/sw/bin:${PATH}
```

And log out and back in again to make the new PATH active (or dot in your profile, if you know what that means).

**7. Test the installation**

Now test it with:

```
identify -version

Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-12-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma png rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib
```

Comment: What if the installation path for libpng and zlib is different from the path where IM will be installed?