# How to tell ImageMagick's configure where to find Libpng and Zlib?

Tags: imagemagick, configure

I was going through this old post [Compile ImageMagick from source with PNG support on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496349/compile-imagemagick-from-source-with-png-support-on-osx).

I did mostly all of what it says with minor changes. Libpng and Zlib are in the following paths

```
/usr/local/libpng
/usr/local/zlib
```

When trying to configure ImageMagick 7.0.5-7 I do it like

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/imagemagick
            CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/libpng/include -I/usr/local/zlib/include'
            LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/libpng/lib -L/usr/local/zlib/lib'
            --enable-shared --enable-delegate-build
```

But still png and zlib are marked as

```
ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes       no
PNG               --with-png=yes        no
```

In some other website I read that I should add to the system variable *PKG_CONFIG_PATH* the path to the *.pc* files. So before running configure I tried also

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/libpng/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/zlib/share/pkgconfig/
```

but still the libraries are not recognized.
Anyone around that knows how to tell the configure script where to look for the libraries?

Comment: Are you sure the compiles of both zlib and libpng  worked properly. Look in the config.log files for each and see if there was an error? If they are fine, try using CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/local/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/local/lib'

Comment: Maybe add `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib` to LDFLAGS

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson nope i was missing pkg-config in my machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working !
After exploring the configure file I figured out that what was missing was **pkg-config** tool.
I just download it from [this site](http://rudix.org/packages/pkg-config.html) installed it.
Run the command above and it works fine now.