# Installing OpenCV 3 in Homebrew using libstdc++

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, homebrew, caffe

I am installing Caffe on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan, which somehow requires that I install OpenCV with libstdc++. To do so, I did "brew update opencv" and adding the following lines below "def install" as mentioned on the Caffe website (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html):

```
def install
      # ADD THE FOLLOWING:
      ENV.append "CXXFLAGS", "-stdlib=libstdc++"
      ENV.append "CFLAGS", "-stdlib=libstdc++"
      ENV.append "LDFLAGS", "-stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++"
      # The following is necessary because libtool likes to strip LDFLAGS:
      ENV["CXX"] = "/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++"
      ...
```

However, when I go install it using "brew install --build-from-source -vd opencv", I get the following error:

> cd /tmp/opencv-20170909-8122-1xa5qpl/opencv-3.3.0/build/modules/dnn &&
>   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.9.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_symlink_library
>   ../../lib/libopencv_dnn.3.3.0.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_dnn.3.3.dylib
>   ../../lib/libopencv_dnn.dylib [ 59%] Built target opencv_dnn make: ***
>   [all] Error 2 /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/debrew.rb:11:in
>   `raise' BuildError: Failed executing: make 
>   1. raise
>   2. ignore
>   3. backtrace
>   4. irb
>   5. shell Choose an action:

Anyone know how to solve this? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Actually, I realized that my original opencv.rb file is producing the exact same problem. How do I fix/find an opencv.rb file that works?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode command line tools? And reinstalled them since any OS upgrade? `xcode-select --install` is the command.

Comment: ... (continued) see first two steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34530109/2836621

Answer (score 1):

It looks like he build you are going for in not compatible with the OS. If installing on Mac would suggest trying [this method](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/) of implementation. It also uses homebrew but allows for a quick and simple implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately things have changed since that tutorial. If you run `brew options opencv3` or `brew options opencv` you will see they have all gone.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Such a bummer if thats true. I installed it just last week tho. I noticed 'brew options' didn't give anything but if you use the commands and tags listed it still worked for me minus '--head' which I just removed from my build as it wasn't need for me.

Comment: I'm no expert, and if anyone else knows better, I am happy to be corrected - and delighted to find someone who actually knows what is going on and can answer some questions. Maybe try running `opencv_version -v` to see what you actually got.